# Configure NGXS and redux DevTools in a NativeScript application

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, nativescript, ngxs, redux-devtools

I am working on a NativeScript application which uses NGXS for state management.

I have downloaded `"@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.3.4"` and initialized in the module in my root module file as `NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot()`

I use `tns run ios` to run the app on a IOS simulator and then attach my VSCode debugger to it using a

> NativeScript Debugger Plugin for VSCode

I am then given a URL like chrome-`devtools://devtools/remote/serve_file/@02e6bde1bbe34e43b309d4ef774b1168d25fd024/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000`

to be able to debug the application in the browser of my choice(Chrome)
I have downloaded the

> Redux DevTools Extension

on Chrome to be able to visualize the state changes. However, nothing shows up in the DevTools window. Am I missing any part of the configuration?

Comment: Have you seen this package, and is it helpful?: https://github.com/team-lambda/nativescript-redux-devtools/tree/master/nativescript-redux-devtools

Comment: Doesn't work with NGXS